# Android Pixel Perfect Alignment

Tags: java, android, xml

[image]

I'm creating a bar at the top of my app much like the one above.

The graphics are embedded into the background and the numbers that represent the level etc is using TextViews.

As you can see the *TextView* has to be *pixel(dp)* perfect to fit in the center of the white bar thingy. With some margins or padding i can achieve that.

***But how do games like that keep the same pixel perfect across all devices?***

I know about *resource qualifiers* and such but some devices within the same bucket have different sizes.

***Is there a good way or trick to achieve the perfect centering across most devices?***

Comment: You'll have the best luck with 9-patch images. Take a look at the developer docs for it http://developer.android.com/tools/help/draw9patch.html

Comment: Im not dealing with images, the background is fine its the textview i need to center align across devices

Comment: "But how do games like that keep the same pixel perfect across all devices?" -- among other things, they do not have "graphics... embedded into the background". They draw the "graphics" as part of drawing "the numbers that represent the level". In your screenshot, the overall background is that purple gradient -- everything else is drawn on top of it.

Comment: The number will still be a textview though? it changes so how can it be an image

Answer (score 0):

In general Android will handle the relative sizes across devices as long as you do everything in relative units and include 9-patch or images for each screensize.

For your question of how to handle images attached to a `TextView`, you can accomplish this a few ways.

A `TextView` will allow you to attach a drawable to it on the top, bottom, left, and right. You can do this with code using the various [`setCompoundDrawable*`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setCompoundDrawablePadding(int)) methods. For example, this will add a drawable to the right and left of the `TextView`.

txtScore.setCompoundDrawables(R.drawable.imageLeft, null, R.drawable.imageRight, null)

You can also do this in XML with the *drawableLeft*, etc properties. You may need to mess with padding and bounds for the drawables.

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtScore"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/imageLeft"
    android:drawableRight="@drawable/imageRight"
    android:drawablePadding="10dp"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:text="125"/>
```

There are a number of different options in code as well if you look over those setCompoundDrawable type APIs for the `TextView`.

Your other option is to create your own `View` that does all of the work for you, but may be overkill if you only use it in one spot.

Again, you will really want to consider a 9-patch image or create an image for each screensize in the drawable folders. This will allow Android to determine which image to use for each device.